# SQL Server Querying An XML Field

Tags: sql-server, xml

I have a table that contains some meta data in an XML field.

For example

```
<Meta>
    <From>tst@test.com</From>
    <To>
        <Address>testing@123.com</Address>
        <Address>2@2.com</Address>
    </To>
    <Subject>ESubject Goes Here</Subject>
</Meta>
```

I want to then be able to query this field to return the following results

```
From                 To                 Subject
tst@test.com         testing@123.com    Subject Goes Here
tst@test.com         2@2.com            Subject Goes Here
```

I've written the following query

```
SELECT
    MetaData.query('data(/Meta/From)') AS [From],
    MetaData.query('data(/Meta/To/Address)') AS [To],
    MetaData.query('data(/Meta/Subject)') AS [Subject]
FROM 
    Documents
```

However this only returns one record for that XML field. It combines both the 2 addresses into one result. Is it possible for split these on to separate records?

The result I'm getting is

```
From                 To                         Subject
tst@test.com         testing@123.com 2@2.com    Subject Goes Here
```

Thanks

Gav

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to return the XML and then parse it using something like the following code:

```
StringReader stream = new StringReader(stringFromSQL);
XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(stream);

while (reader.Read())
{
    // Do stuff
}
```

Where `stringFromSQL` is the whole string as read from your table.